# How to decide and make REST calls corresponding to parent-child relationship

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, backbone.js, cxf

I am working with backbone.js and Apache-CXF Rest-ful webservice.

I have a tree like structure (parent-child relationship)  of nodes.

User can create children for any node from front-end (UI).

At that time what REST call I want to make ?

OPTIONS ARE :

1. A PUT (update) parent request ,I can call to update parent , to the back end.
2. POST (create) child request , I can call to create child from the back end .

My doubt is,  I want to use these two calls or Is there any better method for the same ?

```
var TreeModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults : {

        id : undefined,

        name : "", 

        children : [] 

    },

    urlRoot : '/api/tree'

});
```

is my model.

In my js code I used :

```
   var parent = new Treemodel();

   ..... (some operations)  .....

   var child1 = new Treemodel();

   child1.save();

   parent.children.push(child1);

   parent.save();
```

Is there any better method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works for you, your approach does not look bad.

Another option (though not much better than yours) that comes to my mind is to save only the child to server and then `fetch()` the parent node.  This simplifies your client code logic.

Code would be like this:

```
var parent = new Treemodel();

[...]

var child1 = new Treemodel();

child1.save({
    success: function () {
        parent.fetch();
    }
});
```

In any case, I would recommend you to **save the parent only if child creation succeeds** by adding a "success" callback.  Your code would then look like this:

```
var parent = new Treemodel();

[...]

var child1 = new Treemodel();

child1.save({
    success: function () {
        parent.children.push(child1);
        parent.save();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your answer looks good. But both are almost similar right? " save the parent only if child creation succeeds" (parent.save in callback looks better than my code .) :)

Comment: Yes, they are quite similar.  The difference is that in my first option you don't alter the contents of "parent" model object, but it loads itself from the server, which can be nice if you want to free your client side from "thinking" what to do with the parent: let the server do it.  Kind of "Keep It Simple" style.  But if you're comfortable with your way of doing it, I see nothing bad about it, :-)